# How to recursively multiply all elements of a list with itself to create a matrix? OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I need to create a weight matrix essentially by multiplying all the elements of a list with themselves.
for example if my list is `[1;-1;1;-1]`, the resulting matrix would be

```
[[0;-1;1;-1],
 [-1;0;-1;1],
 [1;-1;0;-1],
 [-1;1;-1;0]]
```

(diagonal is filled with 0's because a node shouldn't be able to lead to itself)

This would be a piece of cake, but it has to be done recursively, with the following constraints:
only `List.hd, List.tl and List.nth` can be used, and as a parameter, I can only pass in the list:

```
let rec listMatrix = fun(myList)->...
```

Is there any way to do this? Or should I just try to find some fundamentally different way to solve this problem? 
Also, only functional approach is allowed, no global variables.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it recursively is as follows:

```
let l = [1;-1;1;-1];;

let rec index xs =
  let idx xs i = match xs with
      [] -> []
    | (x::xss) -> (i,x) :: idx xss (i+1)
  in idx xs 0

fst (x,y) = x
snd (x,y) = y

let rec mult xs ys = match xs with
    [] -> []
  | (x::xss) -> (List.map (fun y->if (fst x == fst y) then 0 else (snd y*snd x)) ys) :: (mult xss ys)

let mult0 xs = mult (index xs) (index xs)
```

What the code does is, as asked, multiplying a vector with itself. The vector is indexed with numbers in order to handle diagonal elements specially.

The output is:

```
# mult0 l;;
- : int list list =
[[0; -1; 1; -1]; [-1; 0; -1; 1]; [1; -1; 0; -1]; [-1; 1; -1; 0]]
```